# How can the SO_RCVBUF be smaller than the TCP receive window? (Windows XP)

Tags: sockets, windows-xp, tcp, winsock

I have an application using TCP on Windows XP. When I call getsockopt with the SO_RCVBUF option, it reports 8192 bytes. However, Wireshark shows the app advertising a receive buffer of 64K. How is this possible?  To have a 64K receive window, doesn't it need a 64K buffer? Are there two different buffers?

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking into this, and I don't think `SO_RCVBUF` and the TCP Window are necessarily the same thing.

If you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx section *"The Windows NT and Windows 2000 Sockets Architecture"* you see that the Windows Kernel Socket driver Afd.sys sits on top of the Transport protocols. It has its own **socket** `SND`/`RCV` buffers which are what you set in the socket options `SO_SNDBUF`, `SO_RCVBUF` or via Afd registry keys.
Then the TCP transport protocol has its own TCP Window Buffer which is the one everyone is familiar with and is set either in the registry Tcpip parameters or is determined automatically **bearing in mind among other things SO_RCVBUF** which I think is where the confusion comes from. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819736.aspx

So I believe data is read from the transport layer into the afd.sys socket buffer `SO_RCVBUF` as needed where it waits to be read out by the application. You would want the `SO_RCVBUF` to be at least as large as the data you hope to read at once.

However I don't know how the `SO_RCVBUF` and TCP Window will interplay. Will TCP wait to ACK data until it is read into `SO_RCVBUF`? That is unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the window size yourself? Make sure you do that before `connect(2)` or `accept(2)`. But again windows might be special in this regard, check the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819736.aspx).

Comment: No, I didn't set the window or the buffer myself. But regardless of who set the sizes, I don't understand how it can advertise a 64K receive window if it only has 8K of memory to hold incoming data.

Comment: It might be that winsock is just lying to you. It looks like 64K is the default for faster then 100Mbps connections under windows.